# Android AlarmManager to continue after reboot / removed from RecentTaskManager

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, intentservice

I would like to implement sending notification to users from server using AlarmManager at the time user pre-set before. Code is as follows:

### MainActivity:

```
public void set_Retrival_then_notifcation_Alarm(Context context, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min, int sec) 
    {
        Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        updateTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        updateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec);
        Intent downloader = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        downloader.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, downloader, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);           
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);                        
    }
```

### ParseService:

```
public class ParseService extends IntentService 
{
    static String Parse_AppID = "abc";  
    static String Parse_ClientKey = "abckey";
    String notification_next_price = "";
    String notification_next_date = "";
    SharedPreferences settings;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder 
    {
        public ParseService getService() 
        {
            return ParseService.this;
        }
    }

    public ParseService() 
    {
        super("ParseService");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
        return START_STICKY ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.d("MyService", "About to execute MyTask");
        new MyTask().execute();
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> 
    {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) 
        {
            Log.d("MyService - MyTask", "Calling doInBackground within MyTask");
            initParse(ParseService.this);
            get_notification_info(ParseService.this);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(Context context, String title, String content) 
    {
        Log.d("MyService - MyTask", "A - sendNotification");
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences("MyApp",0);
        boolean notify_is_on = settings.getBoolean("notify_is_on", true);
        int saved_amount = settings.getInt("saved_amount", 800);

        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        int k = 0;
        try
        {
            k = numberFormat.parse(notification_next_price).intValue();
            if (notify_is_on && (k >= (saved_amount*10000)))
            {
                setNotificationContent(context, k, ""+title, content + "");
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No need notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            setNotificationContent(context, k, "Title2", "Content2");
        }
    } 

    public void setNotificationContent(Context context, int k, String title, String content)
    {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, CurrentResult.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setTicker("Hello")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.b06)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(true) 
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentTitle(""+title)
            .setContentText(""+content)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
         .build();

        startForeground(1337, noti);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    public void initParse(Context context) 
    {
        try 
        {
            ...connection to Parse.com
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void get_notification_info(Context context)
    {       
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Record_db");
        //....getting records from server
        sendNotification(ParseService.this, ""+notification_next_price, ""+notification_next_date);
                    }                   
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Getting server content error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### AlarmBroadcastManager

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public AlarmBroadcastReceiver () {
    }

    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {
         Intent dailyUpdater = new Intent(context, ParseService.class); 
         context.startService(dailyUpdater);
         Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Called context.startService from AlarmReceiver.onReceive");
     }
}
```

### Manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.abc.abc.ParseService" 
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true" />
        <receiver 
            android:name="com.abc.abc.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

### Question:

The fetching records from server and sending to notification are working properly when the app is in the recent task list.

However, if the app is manually removed from the recent task list, the alarmManager and hence the notification are cancelled and no notification is thereby received.

I have googled and most solution are to return `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand`, to register in Manifest, but I have tried with no success.

Could you please help see what the problem is? Why the notification cannot be rebooted after the app is manually removed from the recent task list? Are there any example such that this `ParseService` is working at the user's pre-set time?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "if the app is manually wripped" mean? Please explain **in detail** what you are doing, possibly including screenshots.

Comment: it means the user deliberately remove the app from the recent task list (the recent task list can be launched from long-pressing the Home button)

Comment: On normal Android devices, this should not affect scheduled alarms. Since your question does not appear to have any `AlarmManager` code, it is difficult to comment on that.

Comment: The related AlarmManager code is added to the question above. For further info, the fetchServer & send notification action is performed every 2 days. Yes, I am testing on a normal Android devices, when times goes on, the app is usually automatically being removed by system from the recent task list. Will the alarm be removed if it is removed by system? I have tried removing the app manually from the list, the alarm is not working anymore.

Comment: Most of the app nowadays have notification,  eg,  in some game some rewards are freely obtained every 3 hours and there will be notifications when the rewards are unlocked... there should have standard ways to tackle this problem?  What is missed above?

Comment: Scheduled Alarms are not bound to your process and will not be cancelled when your process is stopped (which happened when the app is not in recents anymore).

Comment: @F43nd1r but the notification really do not activate...do you know why?

Comment: Side note: Your intent service may disappear once it reaches the end of onHandleIntent  and your app can be killed off. There is no guarantee that your async task will run. You can just remove the async task and perform the operation in the intent service, it is already on a background thread.

Answer (score 5):

- You need to store the registered alarms in a local db
- then create an on boot completed receiver

  - in this receiver load all alarms and register them again
- in AlarmBroadcastReceiver class delete this alarm from the db

thats it

Comment: could you please tell more on how to store the registered alarms in a local db?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of AlarmManager you should use `GcmListenerService` this will get notify even your app is removed from the task manager, [GcmListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmListenerService)

Comment: i have not used GCM before. However, my current database is at other third party provider, so i need to transfer the database to GCM cloud?

Comment: Not exactly....both side(Server: where your database is stored and App: you you get push notifications) you have to use GCM. it is so simple, just search in web.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified

```
set_Retrival_then_notifcation_Alarm
```

as follows for testing. Adding 30 second in current time and set alarm.
In mean time kill the app from the recent task to test.

```
 Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cur_cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
        Log.d("Testing", "Calender Set time:"+cur_cal.getTime());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ParseService.class);
        Log.d("Testing", "Intent created");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
        Log.d("Testing", "alarm manager set");
        Toast.makeText(this, "ServiceClass.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You can trigger service from PendingIntent. This will solve the issue if user clear the app from recent task.

As stated by Hossam Alaa  at  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40733562/1920735)  you can do that for boot issue.
Also you don't need a AsyncTask in IntentService. It has a working thread.

Sample of ParseService (Modify as per your need, currently it will wait for 5000 ms and trigger a notification) .

```
public class ParseService extends IntentService {


public ParseService() {
    super("ParseService");
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            setNotificationContent("HELLO","THERE");
            //stopSelf();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public void setNotificationContent( String title, String content)
{
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setTicker("Hello")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentTitle(""+title)
            .setContentText(""+content)
            .setContentIntent(pi).build();

    startForeground(1337, noti);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);


}
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain about "You can trigger service from PendingIntent. This will solve the issue if user clear the app from recent task." ? Did you find a way to avoid the alarm from being completely removed in case the user removed the task from the recent tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Alarms are deleted only if your app is removed or disabled(in app manager), they definitely survive after usual reboot or suspend.

But I am not sure your manifest is setup correctly:
The alarm is sending broadcast to 'AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class' and it will respond if app is alive at the specific moment.

I would suggest to broadcast a custom action with alarm and register it in receiver.

Add to your receiver in manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.abc.abc.action.downloader" />
</intent-filter>
```

And use another intent for alarm like:

```
Intent downloader = new Intent(context, "com.abc.abc.action.downloader");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, downloader, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```